# Getting Kedro globals.yml to work with OmegaConfigLoader

Tags: kedro

I just started evaluating Kedro for use, and I began with a small project where I read data from a MS-SQL Server. The pipeline will run with a few months in between, and with new date ranges every time. To get this parameter (date) into the pipeline I looked into using `globals.yml`. The `kedro run` command works, I have created just one node that loads the data.

I load some parameters from `globals.yml` to use in `catalog.yml`.

- If I use the standard lines in `settings.py`

  ```
  from kedro.config import TemplatedConfigLoader
  CONFIG_LOADER_CLASS = TemplatedConfigLoader

  CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS = {
                        "globals_pattern": "*globals.yml",
  }
  ```

  When doing this, it does run perfectly, BUT **I get a warning message**, specifically this

  ```
  FutureWarning: TemplatedConfigLoader
                        will be deprecated in Kedro 0.19. Please use the
                        OmegaConfigLoader instead. To consult the
                        documentation for OmegaConfigLoader, see here:
                        https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/configuration/advanc
                        ed_configuration.html#omegaconfigloader
  ```
- Perfectionist as I am, **I want to get rid of this warning and be prepared for Kedro 0.19**. Looking at the link in the warning, I replaced the above code in `settings.py` to

  ```
  from kedro.config import OmegaConfigLoader  # new import
  CONFIG_LOADER_CLASS = OmegaConfigLoader

  CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS = {
                       "globals_pattern": "*globals.yml",
  }
  ```

  Then it complains about `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'globals_pattern'`.
- OK so I try to remove the `CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS` thinking it is already there by default. Does not work either.

**How do I get globals.yml to work properly with OmegaConf in Kedro?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now supported:

If you are on 0.18.14, it's also supported in the 0.19.x versions:
https://docs.kedro.org/en/0.18.14/configuration/advanced_configuration.html#how-to-use-global-variables-with-the-omegaconfigloader

Comment: Great work, and thanks! Will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

So `OmegaConfigLoader` doesn't yet support globals, [it's coming very soon...](https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/pull/2921)

For now keep using `TemplatedConfigLoader` as is, from version 0.19.x the `OmegaConfigLoader` will replace it fully and be a lot more powerful in general

Comment: Notice that the `globals` resolver was merged yesterday and should be available in the next version of Kedro, scheduled in about 2-3 weeks

Comment: Great thanks. I will accept the answer, and then if a new answer comes in once it is released change things.